# How to implement like kind of search in GAE JDO 3

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am trying to create a query which will return all rows whose "name" fields values starts with some character in GAE JDO 3

Comment: what have you tried? Please show us some code. Where exactly is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add a property to your model called 'first_letter', and search on that.